# How To Refresh an active datagridview from another form using c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a form that contains a datagridview. When I click on `Add new` Button, a child form appear for inserting a new item into datagridview.

I want to refresh the datasource of datagridview while inserting the new item from the child form.

Comment: What framework are you working in? WinRT, WPF, WinForms?

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i do that easily with vb.net, do you mean thhat there is no way to do it?

Comment: @Mr William: I work with windows forms application, framework 4.5

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking to call the DataBind method on the grid after you've added the item to it. When the dialog box is closed or right after the user selects Add Item, call grid.DataBind().